# React directly renders array without looping

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array `lis` to which I'm pushing elements. When I render this array, react somehow renders the whole array. I thought I need to use `map()` for looping but it somehow rendered the array without the need to use any loops.

**Can you please help me with this?**

```
export default function App() {
  const lis = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    lis.push(i + 1);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {/* thought of using this
      {lis.map(k => k)}   */} //Output : 12345
      {/* but this worked too... why ?? */}
      {lis}        //Output : 12345
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Please visit CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-river-omz30?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: `{lis}` means print the array. So what are you expecting ?

Comment: You can render arrays in JSX. `lis` is an array. `lis.map(...)` returns an array. Same thing. You often see map being used because people map over an array of **data** and return an array of **components** to be rendered. But in your case, when it's just numbers being printed, there's no difference

Comment: Thank you for a quick response. It cleared my doubt. @Jayce444 please post this as an answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The for loop runs and finishes *before* the component is rendered, so when it comes time to show the list, it's already filled. Using a for loop or `map()` makes no difference besides the fact that `map()` is the functional way to iterate over arrays.
That said, you can use `map()` to render new components for every new item, like so:

```js
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const lis = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    lis.push(i + 1);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      
      {/* for every item in the array, render a new <p> element */}
      {lis.map((k) => <p key={k}>{k}</p>)}

      {console.log(lis)}
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note that in cases like that where you'll render a list of components, you have to add a key property or React will scream at you.

Comment: Thank you for your response.